# How to limit time of game in GoT?

Tags: game-of-thrones, play-time

We have played a few times (5-7 probably) and every time single game takes around 6 hours for someone to win. It's not even finished at that point, but somewhere around 6th turn.

Is there a way to reduce time spend on the single match?

Comment: You could try using a timer for each phase of the turns.

Comment: As I recall, games of GoT (first edition, but I doubt it's changed with second edition) were particularly prone to analysis paralysis; https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/122/1926 might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like an issue brought about by some analysis paralysis, as mentioned in the comments on the original question. Check out the linked post ([Countermeasures to "analysis paralysis"?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/122/1926)) for help with dealing with that aspect at a high level.

As far as making Game of Thrones go faster, there are a number of ways you can do it (with the first four bullets borrowed from [the BGG thread on the same topic](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/791189/any-tips-making-game-play-faster)):

- Use a timer for the order placement, negotiation, and order execution phases of each round. This can be done for everyone at once, or by starting the timer once the first or second-last player is done (a la RoboRally or Galaxy Trucker).
- Use text messaging (or another non-verbal method) to do all of the secretive discussion, instead of having players leave the room or try to whisper.
- Have everyone place their orders at the same time, instead of in turns.
- Have printouts of each player's hero cards available, so that they aren't being passed back and forth every battle.
- For anyone who is new to the game, make sure they have read through the rules on their own and had a chance to ask questions *before* the game starts.
- Use social pressure to encourage everyone to go faster. For example, whoever is last to place their orders is in charge of getting drinks/snacks until the next order placement phase.
- Put a timer on the table which can be flipped by anyone at any time who feels like someone is taking too long (a la Codenames).

These are just a few different ways to speed up the game, I'm sure there are more. Using just a few of the above approaches, we got our games down to a reasonable ~90 minutes even with a couple analysis paralysis folks involved.

Comment: Good tips!  However ~90 minutes sounds unrealistic.  When playing online at https://www.thronemaster.net  6 player games takes ~180 minutes.

Comment: @Cohensius We are typically playing a 4 player game, which leaves most of the south unpopulated, so there's a bit more freedom to expand right from the start if you've got ships to get there or land units nearby. When we do play 6 players, I agree that 90 minutes is hard to reach but we can usually do it in about 120-150 minutes.